# Change system user for a domain in Plesk

Tags: plesk

I have a server with Plesk installed, running a couple of webs.

One of them, the-subdomain.com, started as a subdomain of another one, the-domain.com. They were created using the same system user and it was hosted in a subdirectory of httpdocs (httpdocs/the-subdomain).

Now I want to change the-subdomain.com to its own system account, but Plesk does not have the option to do it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: No, currently there is no feature to extract domain or subdomain from subscription to new subscription. The easiest way is to create new subscription and move all data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did:

- Firs, I created another subscription (*the-subdomain2.com*), as Oleg said
- Then, I **copied** all data to new subscription
- After that, I tested all was working fine touching my local hosts file
- Then, I deleted the old subscription
- The last step was to rename *the-subdomain2.com* to *the-subdomain.com*

Unrelated to this, while playing with susbscriptions, I created a system user which then I needed to delete. Plesk hasn't the option to delete the user, so I deleted the account on the machine (`userdel -r THE_USER_TO_DELETE`) and then on the Plesk database (`use psa; delete from sys_users where login='THE_USER_TO_DELETE';`)